# How to make Android app work for different screen sizes

Tags: java, android

I have an activity in my Android app and when I resize it the views change the way the align like they become closer together or more further apart. Any help will be appreciated!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#264563"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="56dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="269dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="57dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="476dp"
    android:background="@drawable/login_plaintext_layout"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName2"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="56dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="336dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="57dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="409dp"
    android:background="@drawable/login_plaintext_layout"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="56dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="407dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="57dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="328dp"
    android:backgroundTint="#ba6f13"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.524" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I would try to focus on basics. Try to follow [this](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) or [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mtYBBInIIE8). But to be more precise the views are behaving like that, because you use parent constraints and hardcoded high margins.

Answer (score 1):

You have many ways of achieving what you want. You should look into the documentation of constraint layout to see all the ways it has to arrange views.

If you want something more extreme you should look into modifiers for your layout files. Just like you can see into this link https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/designing-the-landscape-and-portrait-mode-of-application-in-android/